# Fluid image including navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this site: http://www.bacchica.com.br/

With any window size the navigation bar will be right at the bottom until you scroll.

I'm not sure if I can do it with only using CSS but so far I've made the below;

**HMTL**

```
<div class="container">

<ul class="jquery slideshow">
  <li><img src="01.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="01.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<div class="jquery navbar">
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#s1" class="subNavBtn" id="s1">Section 1</a> 
            <a href="#s2" class="subNavBtn" id="s2">Section 2</a>
            <a href="#s3" class="subNavBtn" id="s3">Section 3</a>
            <a href="#s4" class="subNavBtn" id="s4">Section 4</a>
            <a href="#s5" class="subNavBtn" id="s5">Section 5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width:100%;
}
```

With above there is a slide show and there is a navigation bar underneath the slideshow and showing as 100% width, all I need now is for them to fit in to any window size as a whole.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it only with CSS without jQuery by using the `calc` command. This way you can do something like this:

```
.slideshow {
    height:calc(100% - 100px);
}

.navbar {
    height:100px;
}
```

This way you are telling the browser that the navigation bar has a height of 100 pixels (change it to whatever value you want), and the slideshow will be the whole height of the windows minus the 100 pixels from he height of the navbar. Then the navigation bar will always be at the bottom.

**EDIT**: I tested in local and it works fine, I tried to put it in jsfiddle and it fails. Here it's the code I have, and it works fine on IE and Chrome:

**EDIT 2**: I found why this happened. I forgot to put the doctype. Once I put the doctype html and add height to the container and body, it works fine. [You can see it in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h36E2/).